# Why is it that a non-zero determinant indicates linear independence?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I assume this is because the determinant encodes a sort of "test" for linear independence, so that instead of determining if, for example, three vectors are linearly independent with the definition:

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{i}v_{i} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \alpha_{1}=\alpha_{2}= ... = 0$

Instead you compute the determinant and get your answer directly. If this is correct, how exactly is it encoded? If not, what's going on?

Comment: Think of it as a volume. If the volume is zero then you must have all $n$ vectors lying in an $n-1$ dimentional space. (Not sure why Oliver deleted his answer, seemed good to me.)

Comment: @copper.hat The volume explanation makes a lot of sense for $R^3$, but what about the general case? What's happening there?

Comment: Well, we extrapolate our intuition from $\mathbb{R^3$. One can interpret it in a similar light.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\sum \alpha_iv_i$ is the image of the vector $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)^T$ under the matrix in question. So a linear dependence is equivalent to a non-zero vector being mapped to the zero vector. The latter exists iff the linear map given by the matirx is not injective, which is equivalent to the matric not beig invertible, which is equivalent to the determinant being $0$ (because an explicit inversion formula exists that has the determinant in the denominator and hence fails if the determinant is $0$).

Answer (score 0):

By contrapositive: if three vectors are linearly dependent, their determinant is $0$ since the determinant is a multilinear *alternate* form.

Comment: I have only studied linear algebra, so I don't really know anything about multilinear maps. Is there a linear analogous for this?

Comment: A multilinear map of, say, three variables as here, is just a map which is linear in each variable. It is alternate if it is $0$ when two variables are equal, ans one deduces easily that it is $0$ if the variables are linearly dependent..